# Is it possible to set a custom XLST file for the docbkx-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, docbook

It seems that Docbook Maven  Plugin is using its own XSLT transformation. Is it possible to force my own transformation to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The customizations docbkx provides is same as docbook. I guess you just want to have your own customization layer that imports the docbook xsls.

This is of course possible. See http://blog.kasunbg.org/2010/12/how-to-use-docbkx-tools-as-maven.html

It provides a detailed guide on how to use docbkx-maven-plugin with your own customization layer.

Here's the configuration

```
<configuration>
      <foCustomization>src/docbkx/xsl/fo.xsl</foCustomization>
      <xhtmlCustomization>src/docbkx/xsl/xhtml.xsl </xhtmlCustomization>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally if you want to customize webhelp output you would use the following configuration element

```
<configuration>
  <webhelpCustomization>src/docbkx/xsl/webhelp.xsl</webhelpCustomization>
```